# How to call 'change' event only if node is reordered

Tags: jquery, events, treeview

I have a nestable tree which is designed as follows
https://gist.github.com/Achaius/5291761

I want to trigger this onchange method only if nodes were reordered. But now the current functionality is when I click the element of class 'dd-handle', onchange event is triggering and server side script is called.

This is happening because around line:296, we have
'this.el.trigger('change');'
I want to trigger this change event only if I reordered the list.

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Save the inital order on pageload. In your change event, compare new order to old order. If they are different, an order change has been made:

```
var idList = getIdList();

$('.dd').nestable();

$('.dd').on('change', function (event) {
    var newIDList = getIdList();

    if (newIDList != idList) {
        console.log("Order has been changed");
        idList = newIDList;
    }
});

function getIdList() {
    var idList = '';
    $('.dd-item').each(function () {
        idList += $(this).data('id');
    });

    return idList;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/94NNb/1/

Comment: It is not working when only change the level on node.How can we know that row level has been changed?